# Htaccess Mod rewrite Drupal URL clean-up code stopping my redirect rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, mod-rewrite, redirect, clean-urls

I'm trying to set-up some 301 redirects after a site redesign. Using the following code with the rewrite tule works fine in a test environment

```
RewriteRule ^Old-Page1$ http://www.Domain.com/new-page [R=301,L]
```

But when I move this code to the htaccess file in the new site directory, the redirect pages return a `404`. As though the redirect code is not even being looked at. Is it possible that the `L` flag in the clean URL code is stopping the redirect rules from being read? The code now looks like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico   
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]


RewriteRule ^Old-Page1$ http://www.Domain.com/new-page [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^Old-Page2$ http://www.Domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Would be grateful for any help here. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've managed to sort this out. It seems there was a problem with the clean up code. Possibly the L flag may have been stopping my redirects from getting checked. I flipped the code around, so the Redirect rules for the 301s are above the clean up code. This did the trick